# handling route permissions in mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm working with different types of users(admin, regular, guest) and would like to give each type of user permission to access different routes in a mojolicious app.  My thought is to build a permission table for each user type to be able to access different routes (either by path or more likely by action name).

I was thinking of handling this on a more global level with a `around_dispatch` hook and query a database for a lookup on which actions (subroutines) can be accessed for which user type.

This would look a bit like:

```
$self->hook( around_dispatch => sub ($next,$c) {

    if (logged in user has permissions) {
        $next->();
    } else {
       $c->redirect_to('/permission_error');
    } 
});
```

where I'm looking to determine the action that is called for a given route.  Is there a way to drill down in a `Mojolicious::Controller` object within this hook to do this?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: Added a small example.

Comment: If you use a hook, you probably want something that fires after the routing phase like `around_action`.  In your `around_action` callback you can access `$c->stash('mojo.captures');` which gives you the controller and action. Make sure to check for the `$last` flag also.

Comment: If your access groups are 'inclusive' i.e. admin has all the rights of regular - plus some more, It might be easier to use routes and `under`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pulls all of the information I need:

```
$self->hook(
        around_action => sub {
            my ($next, $c, $action, $last) = @_;
            if (has_permssion($c->current_user,$c->{stash}->{action})) {
                return $next->();
            } else {
                $c->redirect_to('/permission_error');
            }
        }
    );
```

where I am using the `Mojolicious::Plugin::Authentication` to handle authentication and users and the `has_permission` subroutine checks if the supplied user has permission to access the requested route/action.